# Bitwise operations in APL?

Tags: bit-manipulation, apl

We need to make a program that emulates the division of IEEE floating point numbers for my computer architecture class. I pretty much have this done, but I thought it would be interesting to see what the program would look like in APL, yet as far as I can tell there is no (straightforward) way to do bitwise operations in APL (bitwise and/or, shifting, etc...). What is the simplest way to do this in APL, if possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The clean (= the way you want to use) way of doing this in APL is:

1. convert number(s) to a bit vector (or bit matrix or higher dimension
   APL value),
2. do the shift rotate etc. operation on the bit vector, and
3. convert back to the numbers

Steps 1 and 3 are fairly simple: APL has two conversion operators encode (⊤) and decode(⊥) that do it. Bit vectors are only a special case; the operators
work with arbitrary bases (including hex).

Examples:

```
      ⍝ convert 13 to 4-bit vector. The number of 2s is the result length
      2 2 2 2 ⊥ 13
1 1 0 1

      2 ⊥ 1 1 0 1   ⍝ convert back
13
```

An APL programmer would **not** write 2 2 2 2 to indicate the desired length of the result vector, but instead (4⍴2). This is because for longer arguments of ⊤ (like 64 in your case) the code is far more readable.

Negative integers are a bit more tricky because there are different formats like 1-complement or 2-complement. ⊤ and ⊥ work but you have to take some care.

There are a few cool things that ⊤ and ⊥ provide. First of all you can convert
several numbers in one go:

```
      2 2 2 2 ⊤ 1 2 3
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
```

Next, as already said, they work for other bases like 16 for hexadecimal results:

```
      16 16 16 16 ⊤ 50000
12 3 5 0
```

The result is numeric, so you may want to convert it to characters:

```
      '0123456789ABCDEF'[⎕IO+16 16 16 16⊤50000]
C350
```

The most tricky case is floating point (and thus also complex) numbers.

Most APL interpreters have system functions for that, for example ⎕DR in APL68000 or 27 ⎕CR in GNU APL. ⎕DR returns a binary vector directly while 27 ⎕CR in GNU APL converts a 64-bit-IEEE floating point number to a 64-bit 2s-complement integer that can then be converted as described above.

Once you have converted your number(s) to bit vector(s), the rest is simple:

1. Indexing ([]) for accessing individual bits
2. Take (↑) and drop (↓) for shifting bits
3. Rotate (⊖ or ⌽) for rotating bits
4. The boolean functions And/Or/Nand/Nor/Not (∧ ∨ ⍲ ⍱ and ∼) for binary operations.

Comment: Bonus points if you do `((⌈2⍟N)⍴2)⊤N` to generate the specification. "Ceiling of log base 2 of N length array filled with 2s, encode N"

Comment: @SpenserTruex shouldn’t that be `((⌈2⍟(N+÷2))⍴2)⊤N`?  Or even `((0⌈⌈2⍟(N+÷2))⍴2)⊤N` (so it works with 0 too).

Comment: It does have a weird base case, good job spotting that. @lelf

Comment: Since this topic seems still to be of interest: the latest GNU APL (SVN) now has built-in primitive operators for bitweise operations, see https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html#Section-3_002e16.

Comment: You seem to have gotten the encode and decode symbols mixed up.  To convert to binary you use ⊤; to convert back you use ⊥.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your APL system, here is an **unclean** way to do it.  Some APL systems have a []DR system function which allows a fast and loose way to convert the *content* of variables from one data type to another.  If you have Dyalog APL (possibly this will work in APL2000), try this:

```
      )CLEAR
      []IO := 0  // sorry, no APL chars
      []PP := 16
      a := 11 []DR 7.42  // 11 means "type number 1, boolean, 1 bit"
      a
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
      a[42]
1
      a[42] := 0
      645 []DR a   // 645 means "type number 5, double, 64 bit"
7.388750000000003
      )CLEAR
```

Here []DR does the difficult part of converting the floating point number into a vector of bits, then back again.  (This may be precisely the thing which you need to learn in your computer architecture class, but it is not a bad way to check your answer)

**Caution:**  With this technique, you can construct values which are not valid floating point numbers.  This can have the nasty effect of crashing the interpreter, the system, or leaving behind something which can cause a problem later.  Be sure to `)CLEAR` after experimenting.